# laravel insensitive like query builder - oracle

Tags: laravel, oracle11g, datatables

I have oracle 11 as database, and a search in oracle with 'like' query is case sensitive.

so, i want to make a query where i can search insensitive text.

```
$query = DB::table('some_table');

return Datatables::of($query)
  ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
      if ($request->has('search_text')) {
        $query->where(DB::raw("lower(kolom) like '%' || lower('$request->get(search_text)') || '%')"));
      }
  })
->make(true);
```

so i try use statement like in above. but the query result in:

```
select * from some_table where lower(kolom) like '%' || lower('search_text') || '%' is null
```

there's "is null" in there that make the query come to error.
working query should be:

```
select * from some_table where lower(kolom) like '%' || lower('search_text') || '%'
```

what should i do to remove "is null" from there? (I use laravel 5.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-exists-clauses) method instead of `where`.

```
return Datatables::of($query)  ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
  if ($request->has('search_text')) {
    $query->whereRaw(DB::raw("lower(kolom) like '%' || lower('$request->get(search_text)') || '%')"));
  }
})->make(true);
```

Comment: The only thing to add is that you should better use variables' binding for optimal DB interaction. For given example: $query->whereRaw(DB::raw("lower(kolom) like '%' || lower(?) || '%')", [$request->get(search_text)]));